# Trigger event when json file is saved

Tags: json, winforms

I have a Winforms application that changes the ip configuration information and outputs it into a json file. I want to raise an event if the user changes the information in the file so that the configuration info updates again. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use try / catch because if the configuration file is edited then a error occurs. So in the catch use like this

```
try
{

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
if(ex != null)
{
 
}
```